# Download unsuccessful - Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, download

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm creating a project. My task is to download audio (mp3 format). I'm not getting any errors in logcat but when trying to download audio getting "Download unsuccessful". Here is my AsyncTask file:

```
class DownloadAudioFromUrl(val context: Context, val audio: Audio) {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    fun download() {
        try {
            val audioName = audio.title + LocalDateTime.now() + ".mp3"
            val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
            val uri = Uri.parse(audio.filePath)
            val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI)
                .setTitle(audio.title)
                .setDescription("Downloading: " + audio.title)
                .setAllowedOverMetered(true)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
                .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, audioName)
            downloadManager.enqueue(request)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Error downloading: $e")
        }
    }
}
```

curPlayingAudio is not null.
Here is my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.daniil_holdings.soundy">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name=".SoundyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <service android:name=".exoplayer.MusicService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/res"/>
    </provider>
    <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please tell the Android version of used devices.

Comment: Remove the AsyncTask stuff. You dont need that as DownloadManager does all in the background already.

Comment: `return "success"` You should realize that you just started the downloadmanager. There is nothing downloaded yet. So what do you mean with return "success"? A successfull start is all you can say. Not a successfull download.

Comment: It's the latest version of android.

Comment: You are not reacting to much i said and do not manage to tell an Android version.

Comment: Android 12 version.